# Javascript Error - x is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file and I have defined a function called getchartType() and I would like to assign a return string value to the property of javascript object.But I am getting a error in console that getchartType is not defined.

```js
var that = this;
var gadgetConfig = {
  "id": "usage-cities",
  "title": "usage-cities",
  "datasource": "CITY_USAGE",
  "type": "batch",
  "columns": [{
    "name": "max_usage",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }, {
    "name": "metro_area",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "name": "avg_usage",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }, {
    "name": "min_usage",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }],
  "maxUpdateValue": 0,
  "chartConfig": {
    "chartType": "line",
    "yAxis": [2],
    "xAxis": 1,
    "interpolationMode": "monotone"
  },
  "domain": "carbon.super"
};

gadgetConfig.chartConfig["chartType"] = String(that.getChartType());
//console.log(" this is checking "+ gadgetConfig.chartConfig["chartType"]);


var getChartType = function() {
  var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
  var chartTypeQ = prefs.getString('ChartType');
  console.log("===========chartType========" + chartTypeQ);
  console.log("===========typeOf========" + typeof(chartTypeQ));
  return chartTypeQ;
};

console.log("========#### ===========" + getChartType());
```

Can anyone please advice me how to overcome this error?

Comment: `var that = this;` - what is `this` ? (What context are you running the script in)

Comment: You're calling the function before assigning the function expression to `getChartType`. Unlike plain `function` statements, this means the function will not be hoisted. Assign to `getChartType`  before calling it (or use a plain `function` statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work this way:

The problem was that your function (`getChartType()`) was not defined in `this` / `that` when you where calling it.
You need to define a function before calling it in JavaScript:

```
this.getChartType = function...
```

```js
var that = this;
var gadgetConfig = {
  "id": "usage-cities",
  "title": "usage-cities",
  "datasource": "CITY_USAGE",
  "type": "batch",
  "columns": [{
    "name": "max_usage",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }, {
    "name": "metro_area",
    "type": "STRING"
  }, {
    "name": "avg_usage",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }, {
    "name": "min_usage",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  }],
  "maxUpdateValue": 0,
  "chartConfig": {
    "chartType": "line",
    "yAxis": [2],
    "xAxis": 1,
    "interpolationMode": "monotone"
  },
  "domain": "carbon.super"
};


this.getChartType = function() {
  var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
  var chartTypeQ = prefs.getString('ChartType');
  console.log("===========chartType========" + chartTypeQ);
  console.log("===========typeOf========" + typeof(chartTypeQ));
  return chartTypeQ;
};

gadgetConfig.chartConfig["chartType"] = String(that.getChartType());
//console.log(" this is checking "+ gadgetConfig.chartConfig["chartType"]);



console.log("========#### ===========" + getChartType());
```

Comment: How exactly does `getChartType` ever become a property of *any* object? It's just a local variable.

Comment: it does in the context of `this` - check out the example sir, it will call `getCharType`!

Comment: @Pointy, in the context of the questioner, `this` is the global object, so is `that`, and the "locals" are "globals".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi good Point! I updated it to `this.getChartType` in case she is using it in a local scope.

Comment: @CodeiSir well it will work if it's global and `this` is `window` (or whatever), but it won't work as an object property if it's just a local variable in a function.

Comment: @Pointy with `this.getChartType = function...` it will now work in local context as well. Note that I was asking for the context in a comment under question.

Comment: @CodeiSir Oh OK, yes that's fine :)